# Offline page in PWA with nextjs 13 app directory

Tags: progressive-web-apps, next.js13

I am creating a PWA app with the Nextjs 13 app directory. I had worked on react PWA before. there was an offline.html file that would show up if the app was opened in offline mode. I want to achieve this in the Nextjs 13.

How to create a custom offline page for the PWA app in the Nextjs 13 app directory?

** I am using next-pwa package and have configured as it should be. heres an option for offline, fallback. I'm not getting this concept.